# Better backups for Windows (10, 11, etc)

Tags: windows-10, backup, migration, file-history, windows-11

I have a number of desktops, servers & other systems that I run & maintain - for myself, family & friends/colleagues.

I've slowly over the years been inching/trial&erroring towards something that resembles a best-practice setup, often just taking care of things rather than educating folks, wearing and cleaning up the resulting mess, but I have to admit, over the last number of releases, Windows really has become an exceptional experience, overall.

My environment is a BIG mix, but can be described in broad-strokes:

- Linux/UNIX baremetal, VM's & containers - NAS, gateway, IoT, etc

  - NAS's run RAID-5 ZFS/btrfs, with daily snapshots & incremental encrypted off-site/cloud backups

    - Windows' native 'File History' functionality integrates *seamlessly* into this , so *anyone* can do a 'Restore previous version' with no intervention on my part :)
- ~80% of desktops are Windows-based

  - all W10 (home & pro)
  - & 1x W11 I'm *dogfooding* to test before deployment
- Various mobile devices & tablets (primarily Androids)
- Hooked into live/o365/hello/OneDrive, so Preferences & Settings (mostly) syncs across desktops OK (with caveats), and online backups/copies Desktops & Documents are sync'd.

  - Settings & Preferences don't always sync properly, so the suitability of this mechanism/approach is in question
  - Anything else is simply too big or I'm not comfortable stashing in an arbitrary folder online, such as confidential data & media. This is handled on my "local cloud"
- Various OneDrive data - private, personal, shared, org, etc - is backed *by the NAS*, pulling data from various clouds (including GDrive) by using something like *rclone*, rather than backing multiple and duplicate or conflicting copies of the same data from every desktop instance, so all OneDrive/GDrive paths need to be excluded from 'File History'

Overall this strategy has worked OK, but usability has been... shall we say... less than ideal.

- It's not exactly *intuitive*, i.e. what gets backed up, what gets excluded, and what are the results

  - Yes, yes I know where to find some of those values/settings, but it's not streamlined very well, i.e. in disparate places & configs, and a *lot* of stitches are dropped due to lack of visibility or means for oversight
- By 'default', I back up *%HOMEPATH%*, so that I can quickly rebuild a setup when I nuke it.

  - The reasoning is that this is analogous to POSIX */home*, where you can essentially reconstitute your desktop form a thin rebuild/re-provisioning. (Roaming profiles)
- Some data - such as profile information (settings, configs, etc) - is resides in *%HOMEPATH%\Appdata*, so I need to include some of that in my backup set(s), but 'File History' does not seem to respect this inclusion.
- From what I can gather, the action by *'File History'* is to automatically back up libraries, irrespective of what's linked inside, so I've tried to address backups by creating a "BackThisUp" library, and linking dirs/folders I want to back up using the Explorer "Include in library" context menu. Not ideal, but provides a degree of control.

Nowhere is there really sufficient controls over this, similar to the legacy *"Back up and Restore (Windows 7)"* mechanism for pre-selecting/deselecting suggested defaults, or the ability to easily/intuitively change that, so overall one's flying a little blind.

Unfortunately much of this (quite limited) UX has been kneecapped in W11!

W11 no longer has the *Settings*[⚙] backup mechanism, meaning that the little control there was over backups has been removed, and for no apparent reason I can see!

I've had some success having a crack at *%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration\Config[12].xml* , but information on this is sparse and there don't seem to be tools available to do an adequate job of tweaking this, and this is honestly not something that resembles a solution.

Overall this might not be such a significant issue if there were other MS-native tools available to meet the same need, such as MMC plugins, or as an *'Optional Feature'*.

I've found *WinGet* & making use of *Windows Admin Server* (WAC) - what a find! - but those don't have native backup tools or functionality to achieve this goal.
*Windows Server Backup* (WSB) does seem like the better solution here, but from what I can tell it's not available on desktop platforms or as in installable binary.

The closest I could find was *'[Paragon Backup & Recovery CE](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/br-free/)'* which allows me to make selective incremental snapshot backups at or close to filesystem-level, to a VHD on a network target of my choice, which is almost perfect!

I appreciate that this is probably that's edging into AD/GPO territory, but it's really not a suitable solution for n<25 end-points, most of whom are not under my control, such as spouse/partner's work-machine(s) or other WfH asking for help.

Q's:

- What is a better solution or approach for managing backups?
- Are there any MS-native tools I'm unaware of to better manage this?
- Is there an approach I'm ignorant of?

Any feedback, insight or guidance re this would be appreciated

Comment: Apologies for the close vote.  You have obviously put a lot of thought into this question.  Unfortunately this is not a good fit for Superuser and is off-topic here both because its Opinion based and is, in arguably a software recommendation request.

Comment: all good, @davidgo.

If you know of a more appropriate place, I'd be happy to re/x-post.

Ideally I would like to employ OS/MS-native mechanisms rather than introducing additional variables into the mix.